# How to spark-submit a jar in a Spark docker-compose network?

Tags: java, scala, docker, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to setup and use a local Spark development environment using docker-compose.
I created a docker-compose stack made up of 3 services:

1. a Spark **master** using [bitnami/spark](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/spark)
2. one Spark **worker** using [bitnami/spark](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/spark)
3. a *development container* with **Scala** and **sbt** (based on [hseeberger/scala-sbt](https://hub.docker.com/r/hseeberger/scala-sbt/))

Working in the *development container*, I created a very simple *HelloWorld* scala app and built it using `sbt assembly`, setting the *spark-core* dependency with **Provided** scope.

Now I want to run the *HelloWorld* jar as a job on my small Spark cluster. I managed to run the job with `--deploy-mode cluster` by copying the jar on the Spark worker container and executing `spark-submit` from the worker itself. The job logs appear correctly on the Spark browser UI. **But it is this the right way?**

How would I do it with more workers? I tried to `spark-submit` the job from the Spark master but it only works in `--deploy-mode=client` and in such case the job logs don't appear on the browser UI. If I try running it with `--deploy-mode cluster` it gives me a *File Not Found* error on the *HelloWorld* jar.

To sum up

- I am getting confused with the difference of client/cluster deploy mode
- I am not sure about where (i.e. which node) the `spark-submit` command should be executed
- I am not understanding if I am supposed to copy the jar manually on each worker or if there's a better way to distributed the jar file

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can configure NAS or if this run as K8S Kubernetes then map a volume and keep the required jars there. then spark submit with the `--jars` flag.